# Querying database using 'with' and not getting the expected outcome

Tags: mysql, many-to-many, adonis.js

So I have two tables that share a many to many relationship:

1) `Games`, with info from matches created by users and

2) `Users`.

Apart from the user/games relationship where a `game` belongs to many `users` and a `user` belongs to many `games`, there's also a relationship where a `user` can APPLY for many `games` and a `game` can BE APPLIED for by many `users`. For this relationship I created a junction table called `requests`.

I'm using AdonisJs, so I set the model `Games` with

```
applicants () {
  return this.belongsToMany(
    'App/Models/User',
    'game_id',
    'applicant_id'
  ).pivotTable('requests')
}
```

and the model `Users` with

```
applications () {
  return this.belongsToMany(
    'App/Models/Game',
    'applicant_id',
    'game_id'
  ).pivotTable('requests')
}
```

I need to query for all the users that applied to any of the authenticated user's games (defined by having said user's id as `user_id`)

When I use the code

```
async getAllUserGames ({ auth, response }) {
  const allUserGames = await Game.query()
    .where('user_id', auth.current.user.id)
    .with('applicants')
    .firstOrFail()
  return response.json({
    status: 'success',
    data: allUserGames
  })
}
```

it works, but as I used `.firstOrFail()` I only get the info from the first game that has an application.

If I get rid of this line it doesn't return any of the applicants, only the user's games, as if I didn't have the line `.with('applicants')` also.

I'm still trying to get my grip around querying databases, so I would appreciate any insight as to why this is happening.

Answer (score 1):

Did you find a solution for your problem ?
Your code is correct, just replace the

```
.firstOrFail()
```

By

```
.fetch()
```

Or

```
.findOrFail()
```

Since **firstOrFail** will only return the first element matching your query

Usually when it comes to use relations with adonisjs, you need to call the method that will tell lucid to fetch the elements matching your query.

Once your retrieve allUserGames, you will need to update your query so that it will match exactly what you need.

**firstOrFail** returns a single element whereas **findOrFail** and **fetch** will return a pagination object

```
const { rows: realUserGames } = allUserGames
```

The complete example would be

```
async getAllUserGames ({ auth, response }) {
  const allUserGames = await Game.query()
    .where('user_id', auth.current.user.id)
    .with('applicants')
    //.findOrFail()
    .fetch()

  const { rows: realUserGames } = allUserGames

  return response.json({
    status: 'success',
    data: realUserGames
  })
}
```

### References

- https://adonisjs.com/docs/4.1/lucid#_findorfail
- https://adonisjs.com/docs/4.1/relationships#_eagerloading

Comment: Thanks! I actually don't remember if I have tried your solution or if I found a way to make it work at all. I think I eventually implemented a different functionality to my app. I appreciate your response!